# PostgreSQL and PostGIS for extracting specific area covered by a ROI polygon

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, postgis, polygon, raster

Dear stackoverflow community,

I am working with a digital elevation point cloud (mean point desnity 4-10 pts/m², positional precision +/- 30 cm, height precision +/- 15 cm, area: 1000x1000m). I interpolated a raster file with an resolution of 1m x 1m. Further denoted as DEM.

Furthermore, I have a 4 channel, high-precision, orthographic picture (mean positional precision is +/- 20-30 cm, horizontal resolution is 20cm x 20cm) for the same area. Further denoted as DOP

I stored both in a PostgreSQL-DB with PostGIS extension and a tiling size of 40x40.

The target to create polygons and request raster data of both layers mentioned above covered by those polygons.
I created a polygon with an extend of e.\,g. 32 x 32m. This polygon become shifted over the area of interest, so that the whole area is covered by many polygons.
Afterwards I created a query for the covered raster data:

```
WITH 
    ref AS(
            SELECT 
            ST_Transform(rast,25832) AS align_to
            FROM geodata.dsm LIMIT 1
    ), 
    aligned AS(
        SELECT
            ST_Union(
                ST_Transform(
                        ST_Clip(
                                dsm.rast,
                                    p.geom
                            ),
                            align_to
                    )
        ) as rast1,
            ST_Union(
                ST_AsRaster(
                        p.geom,
                            align_to
                    )
            ) rast2
            FROM 
            geodata.dsm AS dsm,
            public.classification_result_overlap_35cm_ss8 AS p
        CROSS JOIN ref
        WHERE 
        p.gid=1 AND ST_Intersects(dsm.rast, p.geom) 
    )
    SELECT
        ST_MapAlgebra(rast1, rast2,'[rast1]') as raster FROM aligned;
```

After a visual inspection of the results, it became obvious, that the mapping between the queried DEM and DOP is not 100% exact. It became more evident, when I made the polygon size smaller, lets say 8 x 8m.
I queried with ST_GeoReference the upper left coordinates of the queried DEM and DOP data and determined with pyproj.Geod(...).inv the distance between the upper left coordinates. I figured out, that the shift between the upper left coordinates of the DEM and DOP data ranges between 0 and 1.2. Might it be, that I did something wrong within my query? I thought maybe the max difference between DEM and DOP could result through the different horizontal resolution of the datasets. In this case, the maximum difference between the data could be \sqrt{2} m.

By the way, does someone have a hint for me, to further accelerate this query?

System setting:

- DB: PostgreSQL version 12.1
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Extension: POSTGIS="3.0.0 r17983" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120"
  GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 "PROJ="6.3.0" GDAL="GDAL 3.1.0dev-437c92a187, released 2020/01/05" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.12.1" RASTER

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards